# unordered_set count function returns wrong value

Tags: c++, unordered-map, unordered-set

Why does `set.count('a')` output `1` when there are `3` a's?

Program:

```
bool isAnagram(string s, string t) {

    unordered_set<char> set;

    for(int i=0; i<s.size(); i++){
        set.insert(s[i]);
    }

    cout << endl << set.count('a') << endl;
    return false;
}
```

Input:

```
s = 'anagram'
```

Output:

```
1
```

Comment: First sentence from the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_set/count): _"Returns the number of elements with key that compares equal to the specified argument key, which is **either 1 or 0** since this container does not allow duplicates."_

Comment: You should probably review the mathematical concept of a set.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There's only one `a` in the set. If you want multiple `a`s you need to use a `multiset`.

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <set>
#include <string>

size_t count_char(const std::string& s, char ch) {
    // fill the set directly using the strings begin and end iterators
    std::multiset<char> set(s.begin(), s.end());

    return set.count(ch);
}

int main() {
    std::cout << count_char("anagram", 'a') << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
3
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to specify the range in count function :

```
count (InputIterator first, InputIterator last, const T& val)
```

Example:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;

int main(){
    string s= "anagram";

    cout << count(s.begin(), s.end(), 'a') << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Output:

```
3
```